# Can't finish setup for the assistant

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I followed this guide for installing the google assistant library on my raspberry pi 3b with USB out and USB mic.
Link to guide: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/

I get all the way to "run the sample code" without errors but when I run the sample code I get this:

```
 googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project_id SAMPLE_PROJECT_ID --device_model_id SAMPLE_MODEL_ID
device_model_id: SAMPLE_MODEL_ID

device_id: SAMPLE_DEVICE_ID

https://embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/v1alpha2/projects/SAMPLE_PROJECT_ID/devices/SAMPLE_DEVICE_ID 403

ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
[1726:1743:ERROR:http_client_with_backoff.cc(113)] Retrying request with http_status=200 request_id=1
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you try saying "Ok Google"?

Comment: Yup, doesn't do anything :/